# How to fix Among Us authentication issues on Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch, among-us

When I try to join a private room in Among Us on Switch, I get this error:

[image: Among us servers couldn't authenticate you]

I opened the profile section in the menue, and clicked "sign in", yet the error persists. Any way to fix this? I've tried uninstalling the game, removing my savegame data, reinstalling the game, signing in again, and yet the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vT-WJuwCs_QxZPuvRQkWDLzsSU5ktVlFAEz2M5qF1MtFhkZ8z39bfnPcqOQlIeuIYQTI-xiTuHlQ5aF/pub) created by innersloth, it looks like it's a server side/traffic issue...

[image]